# WCF Security - Fastest way to do custom/database based authorization

Tags: c#, sql, wcf

I was wondering if there is an easy way to check if the user has access to a specific method, **controlling the user permission thru a custom database**.

I used to pass the "User" object on every single method, then validate if he does or doesnt has access to that method, just like that

```
[OperationContract]
public void Foo(UserInformation user, string param1, string param2) {
    //Check if the user has permission to run this method
    if (!Security.CheckPermission(user,"Foo")) {
        ...throws an exception or something like that
    }
}
```

I'm sure that there are better ways to do that, one example would be a Role based authorization, but I can't use SQL Server Role provider as my main database is on Oracle and the application already have custom tables where user permissions are stored.

Unafortunatelly, I cant change the database or how users has access to those functions.

I did some research on http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com but no luck.

Comment: You can use `PrincipalPermission` attribute along AspNetMembership provider for method level permission check in WCF. I have used like this : `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = MyPermissonEnum.AlloFoo)][OperationContract]
public void Foo(UserInformation user, string param1, string param2)`

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by _controlling the user permission thru a custom database_? The permission of each method is configurable in the DB?

Comment: I do not see a reason why RoleBased Authorization cannot be implemted in your CheckPermission Method... Of cause your UserInformation class should have an implemetation of a Role property in this case

Comment: Exactly @LostInComputer.

Yaugen, Sql server role based authorization wouldnt work because I dont use SQL Server at all.